# Scala-js - Navigator.oscpu

Tags: scala.js

Can you advice me how to get Navigator.oscpu using Scala-js? Mapping to native Navigator does not seems to have the oscpu. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/oscpu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a Firefox-only feature (based on a quick look around), so it's not supported by Scala.js out of the box. You'll need to add it yourself, by adding a side-facade to Navigator. This isn't terribly hard -- see [the definition of BeaconNavigator](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js-dom/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scalajs/dom/experimental/beacon/package.scala) for an example of how to do this.

So you would need something like (untested):

```
  @js.native
  trait OSCPUNavigator extends js.Object {
    def oscpu: String = js.native
  }

  implicit def toOSCPUNavigator(n: Navigator): OSCPUNavigator =
    n.asInstanceOf[OSCPUNavigator]
```

Basically, you define a trait with `oscpu` on it, and you tell Scala.js how to see a `Navigator` as that trait.

Mind, though, it'll still only work on Firefox. I suspect it'll throw errors on other browsers...

Comment: You are right. It works on Firefox only. A simple mapping like this works  

@native
trait Navigator extends Object {
  val oscpu:String       
}