# How to map js.UndefOr[T] <–> Option[T] with js.native in Scala.js?

Tags: scala, scala.js

I am trying to extend the `Navigator` with the `oscpu` property. This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37399002/5107545) and the implementation works perfectly as proposed by [Justin du Coeur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1245509/justin-du-coeur). The thing is, when I execute the code in a browser other than Firefox, I get an `UndefinedBehaviorError` exception which is logical since this property only exists in Firefox.

However, instead of receiving an exception, I simply want to use `Option`. So if it does not exist, it would be `None` and if it does I would get `Some("OSCPU info")`.

How can I make this work? I tried the following approach, but I am not sure how I can convert to `Option`.

```
@js.native
trait OSCPUNavigator extends js.Object {
  def oscpu: js.UndefOr[String] = js.native
}
implicit def toOSCPUNavigator(n: Navigator): OSCPUNavigator =
    n.asInstanceOf[OSCPUNavigator]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert a `js.UndefOr[A]` to an `Option[A]` with `x.toOption`.

The opposite conversion is also possible as `x.orUndefined`, but requires the following import:

```
import scala.scalajs.js.JSConverters._
```

This is documented at https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/types.html

Comment: Thanks! That perfectly works! However, can you please tell me if my `trait` is correctly _designed_ as it is or should I have `def oscpu: String = js.native` instead and catch the exception in case a browser does not have the `oscpu` property?

Comment: The `js.UndefOr` is definitely the way to go. You must never catch an `UndefinedBehaviorError`, because the behavior of your program will go berserk in fullOpt mode.

Comment: Beware: `js.UndefOr[A]` may also contain `null`, depending on JS code you are facing. If this is the case, you need to handle this case separately.